# ROS2 as shared library in existing application

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to integrate ROS2 inside an existing application. Is there a way to build a ROS2 node as shared library?

The application is not conductive to turn into a library that can be used inside a ROS2 node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285628/ros2-as-shared-library-in-existing-application/) by [Jesper](https://answers.ros.org/users/34148/jesper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Certainly. The recommended way to write ROS2 nodes is as a class which can easily be compiled into a library and integrated into an existing application.

For example take a look at our basic talker demo: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/talker.cpp

The node is created as a class. There's a little bit of boilerplate setup that you'll need to do to that can be seen in the main function. But there's no requirement that it happen in main. The can easily be embedded into another application.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0